# Spatial dimension of galaxy filaments

Tags: cosmology, galaxies, structure-formation

[Galaxy filaments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_filament) are "amongst the largest known cosmic structures in the Universe. They [...] form the boundaries between large voids in the Universe."

As their name suggests, [filaments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filament) are essentially 1-dimensional objects (significantly longer and wider than thick, and significantly longer than wide), but how can such objects be the (very) boundaries of 3-dimensional [voids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_%28astronomy%29)?

In the same Wikipedia article, "supercluster complexes", "great walls", and "great attractors" are proposed as synonyms for "filaments" which suggest other dimensions ($d$):

- unspecified for "complexes"
- $d=2$ for "walls"
- fractal ($1 < d < 2$ or $2 < d < 3$) for "attractors"

What is/can be said about the dimension of these cosmic objects?

Comment: A complex is a generic structure of superclusters. So d~1 is fine. And it says "great walls" not "walls". For a wall, d=2. But picture the Great Wall of China. compare the length to the height and the height to the width. d~1.

Comment: Picture an array of intersecting bubbles. Where each intersection occurs, it forms a ring. If a center bubble intersects bubbles on all sides, then it has many of these rings. While the space between the rings is void, the positioning of all of them roughly define the center of the center bubble. Similarly, the galactic filaments do not form continuous boundaries, but they roughly make a "wire-mesh" defining the shapes of large voids

Comment: For a *generic* structure of superclusters I would assume d~3: they are *somehow* arranged.

Comment: This is far too half-baked to comprise an answer, but, given the resemblance between the filaments and an inverted version of a planetary atmosphere containing numerous vortices, you might want to look at cosmologies that require a prevalent (however marginally) direction of rotation, together with sequential reductions in that rotation's scales, such as Poplawski's cosmology with torsion and, in particular, his 2011 "Matter-antimatter asymmetry and dark matter from torsion", whose math is far beyond me.

Comment: I've got to add that I really like Jim's observations, as I'd drafted some notes a few years ago describing the universe as "a cage of filaments".  Those observations seem disparate from my own posting, although meteorologists do refer to the structures that produce the smallest vortices as "cells".

Comment: @Edouard: Are you cheating (with tongue-in-cheek) that you "independently formulated Olbers' Paradox at age 7" - or is this the plain truth? (It's hard to believe without knowing the context.) What do you do today (next to formulating paradoxes)?

Comment: On a hot afternoon on my primary school's playground in Miami, during my 2nd year there (1955), I wondered why, if the universe was infinite and filled with stars, the sky wasn't a sheet of fire.  (I'm not sure where I'd gotten the idea that the u. was infinite and filled with stars, but it may've been from a nun at a catechism class that I attended weekly.)  The teachers (the older of which felt the galaxy to BE the universe, with which the younger ones disagreed) sent me from one to another of their number with my question, and  made me M.C.of an annual recital (not pleasant for a shy kid).

Comment: Re your 2nd question, I'm retired, after a career that involved French and  Spanish interpreting for a telephone system in various American cities.

Comment: @Edouard: In case "interpreting" has to do with "translating" you might want to have a look at this question of mine: [What is the actual quality of machine translations?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/12659/what-is-the-actual-quality-of-machine-translations) which I just asked the other day. In any case: I'm really impressed of what a 7-year-old can achieve! (BTW: What is an "M.C. of an annual recital"?)

Comment: I lack the reputation to answer on that site, and am not educated re AI, but I'd say that computers don't convey the relation of language to music:  Spoken Spanish, a logical language that's extremely easy to learn, conveys the spacing between words through rhythm, whereas spoken French conveys it by a complicated mix between the English system of pauses between words and the rhythmic Latin system, which makes it easy for English speakers to learn to read but very difficult for them to learn to speak.  (M.C. is Master of Ceremonies; annual recitals include folk dances, poetry reading, etc.)

Comment: @Edouard: Did you ever have to do with "music", "rhythm" and "pauses" in your daily course of "interpreting" French and Spanish? Did these characteristics of languages play a proper role in your daily work? (I'm just curious.)

Comment: Perhaps the staffers could move this conversation to chat, so I could answer your last questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94650/discussion-between-hans-peter-stricker-and-edouard).

Comment: "Late in the day", it appears that plasma filaments (AKA "galactic filaments") may be recovering some considerable importance in cosmology, now that JWST data has effectively trashed the plausibility of the Big Bang Theory.  Anyone interested might want to have a look at https://www.ldolphin.org/nobigbang.html  .  I'd poetically described the universe as "a cage of filaments" in some notes, &, although gmail only kept them for 1 year, further digging dredged the concept back up!  Foolish immortals may find safety in numbers!  Viva PSE!